# Do something if the protocol buffer contract isn't followed both ends?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Just starting out with protocol buffers and getting a little confused.

I've written my own raw TCP socket server and added protocol buffers on top instead of JSON.

I would like to ensure the contract of protocol buffer messages are followed and handle cases where they arent, is this possible?

Example, if the client has a protocol buffer class of

```
[ProtoContract]
public class WelcomeMessage
{
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Message {get;set;}
}
```

But the server has one of

```
[ProtoContract]
public class WelcomeClient
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int MagicNumber {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string WelcomeMessage {get;set;}
}
```

MagicNumber gets set to 0 the default value, but this causes unexpected situations. How can I handle these sorts of cases?

I am simply this for deserializing from a byte array:

```
public class ProtocolBufferUtilities
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] data)
    {
        using var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
        var result = Serializer.Deserialize<T>(stream);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the client and server are talking different contracts, then you'd expect that any message sent between them could cause the receiving end's deserialiser to return an error. Drop the message, connection, etc; it's not going to work.

**Separate Your Messages First!**

But lets step back a bit, to the use of a raw socket. GPB wireformat is not self-demarcating, you have to have another way of telling when the byte stream for one message stops and another starts. An easy way to do this is to adopt ZeroMQ, which is message orientated (and not stream orientated like a raw socket is).

**Drop Connections on Error**

ZeroMQ can then be used to communicate that both ends are happy that they're talking the same contract. For example, if the receiving end gets a message, has a go at de-serialising the message and gets an error returned, the receiving end can close down its end of the connection, and clean up the socket (getting rid of any unconsumed messages).

ZeroMQ allows the sending end to monitor for this kind of event; if sending a message is followed by "connection was closed by the other end", that's a pretty good hint that all is not well.

This is in fact how I do this kind of thing (though not with ZeroMQ and not with GPB, but the principle is the same). If forced to drop a connection because a message makes no sense, I later bring the connection back up, see if the other end has started to make sense.

The nice thing about this is that, if the other end has been stopped, updated to the correct version and restarted, one is not having to restart the whole system (client and server). The receiving end just sits there, bringing up the connection, trying & failing, until someone puts things right.

**Use a .proto File?**

You're building your contract in a "code first" style, instead of the "schema first" approach using a .proto file and the protoc compiler to generate the C# code.

I prefer the latter because it's easier to take advantage of improvements in generated code that Google may have implemented in `protoc`; you mostly just recompile. Also, it becomes easy for different parts of a project to be written in different languages, the .proto file defining the contract.

**Contract Incompleteness**

With GPB, contracts are incomplete. There's no way to express the range of acceptable values for a number, or the acceptable length of lists in a .proto file. In your example, if the sender wants to send a very long string, the receiver has no choice but to suck it up and deal with it.

So with GPB, the only way to deal with this is to agree such constraints outside of the .proto file.

Perhaps in the code first approach you're following it's possible to have a validator method that can check that all is as it should be, and (because it's code first) it's the "single point of truth" for the constraints.

Other technologies do it better. ASN.1 schema syntax allows the definition of constraints on value and length, and generated code will refuse to serialise out-of-spec objects, and refuse to deserialise non-compliant incoming wireformat.

Some of the tools for ASN.1 do "stream deserialisers", which parse data as it's read from a stream (note that some ASN.1 wireformats are self demarcating!). What this means is that, as data is read from a network socket, it is evaluated there and then, including against value and length constraints. This is really useful, as deserialisation errors can be returned on the very first byte in the socket stream that is wrong. That allows the program to drop the connection on receipt of that first wrong byte. Arguably this can be made into a pretty strong security function: "Talk sense, or I close the socket on your first hiccup". It's a good way of fending off buffer overflow attacks.